# Tomcat execute service synchronized

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

It's look like I broke my mind. I've created new project with Tomcat 9 (with 8 the same) on Java 9 (on 8 the same). It has only one servlet

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(new Date().getTime() /1000 + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Start");
        /*long i = 0;

        while (i < 3000000000L) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                i++;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }*/
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        System.out.println(new Date().getTime()/1000 + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Done");
    }
}
```

All my experience said me that on that method works asynchronously, but what I call servlet through 3 tabs in my browser (simultaneously as possible), I have this picture in my log:

```
1492723549 http-nio-9999-exec-2 Start
1492723551 http-nio-9999-exec-2 Done
1492723551 http-nio-9999-exec-1 Start
1492723553 http-nio-9999-exec-1 Done
1492723553 http-nio-9999-exec-3 Start
1492723555 http-nio-9999-exec-3 Done
```

It is seen that every request locks method untils it will be done. Can someone tell me why? I really expect 3 simultaneously Starts and after 2 secs 3 Dones.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have a `Thread.sleep(2000);`? You're using non blocking io, and you are blocking.

Comment: I want to block one thread to emulate some hard work. The other threads from pool is free. Isn't it?

Comment: Don't block to do "hard work". Use [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). For [example](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jvmc3/).

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'll will try CompletableFuture for my "hard work". But that is not the point. I'am asking about why other threads enter into service method only after previous done... This behaviour looks like methid is synchronized, but, as I think, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [servlet specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf):

> For a servlet not hosted in a distributed environment (the default),
> the servlet  container must use only one instance per servlet
> declaration. However, for a servlet  implementing the
> SingleThreadModel  interface, the servlet container may  instantiate
> multiple instances to handle a heavy request load and serialize
> requests  to a particular instance.
>
> In the case where a servlet was deployed as part of an application
> marked in the deployment descriptor as distributable, a container may
> have only one instance per servlet declaration per Java Virtual
> Machine (JVM). However, if the servlet in a distributable application
> implements the SingleThreadModel interface, the container may
> instantiate multiple instances of that servlet in each JVM of the
> container.

Also, [here](https://books.google.ru/books?id=oaiJAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT88&lpg=PT88&dq=A%20web%20server%20such%20as%20Tomcat%20can%20instantiate%20arbitrarily&source=bl&ots=Y4UYpZmpm3&sig=W-DUHnJFT9EGbT_yAT9tsMHTceo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwwLXSp7XTAhVGhSwKHaIEB_4Q6AEILTAC#v=onepage&q=A%20web%20server%20such%20as%20Tomcat%20can%20instantiate%20arbitrarily&f=false) you could find some information about tomcat:

> A web server such as Tomcat can instantiate arbitrarily many instances
> of a servlet, although the number is typically small (e.g., 1 through
> 4). The web server itself makes the decision.

So, it's absolutely normal that you have only one instance of servlet in your app.

Please, make sure that you really need to override HttpServlet.service() method, because, as it said in [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#service-javax.servlet.ServletRequest-javax.servlet.ServletResponse-):

> There's no need to override this method